# Popup editing modal in EE3 control panel?

Tags: control-panel, ee3, textarea, modal

In EE2's control panel, when working in a textarea field, there was an option to open a larger modal, effectively giving one a much larger screen area for editing. Then you'd either cancel the changes you made in that modal window, or publish to field.

I'm not finding this in EE3.x control panel. Am I just missing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was removed in EE3.  I know that WYGWAM had the ability to edit in full screen view. You should still have the ability to expand the text area from the bottom right hand corner though.